# MVC3 ASP Post information from ASP to PHP over hreff

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-3, hyperlink, session-variables

On the site I have the following code at my header and if the user has logged in, then the link "Tracking" sends the user to the following link.
How can i send the same time some session information like the customerid? The header is on an MVC3 ASP site and the link directs to a PHP Site which is displayed internally through an iframe.

```
<li class="al-contact">@if (Model.CurrentUser != null)
        {  if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
                                 {
                                    <a href="http://webpilot/content/TrackingSystem_order" target="_self">Tracking</a>
                                  }
                                  } else { 
                }
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `CustomerID` as a property of your viewmodel / base viewmodel. Get it from Session or any other place in your action method and then simply pass it to the view. Use it there to build the url to the external website.

```
public class TrackingListViewModel
{
  public int CustomerID { set;get;}
  //Other relevant Viewmodel properties
}
```

in your Action method set the value.

```
public ActionResult List()
{
  var vm=new TrackingListViewModel();
  vm.CustmoerID=124; 
  // hardcoded for demo. you may read from session or somewhere and set it 
  return View(vm);
}
```

and in the view, send that as the querystring(assuming that site's page will read the querystring value and process it, You need to know what querystring key they are expecting. The below sample assumes they will read the key called "`customer`"

```
@model TrackingListViewModel

<li class="al-contact">
 @if (Model.CurrentUser != null)
 { if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      <a href="http://somewebsite/TrackingSystem_order?id=@Model.CustomerID"
                                                      target="_self">Tracking</a>
     }
 } 
</li>
```